# BigCommerce Stencil Start

Tags: bigcommerce

After initializing Stencil, I get the following error when I want to start Stencil:
`The BigCommerce Store you are pointing to either does not exist or is not available at this time.`
The store URL, usr, and pass are correct. The port is available.

Don't know what to do now.

Comment: you should be using a store-xxxxx.mybigcommerce.com url and make sure there's no url slug after the path. Make sure it isn't down for maintenance either.

Comment: You mean the temporary URL you're given before you transfer it to your domain?

Comment: I just tried with https://store-tc515.mybigcommerce.com and I still get the same message.

Comment: Is it down for maintenance?